# Merge missed commits

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

Recently I met a problem while merging code with svn. Here is the scenario:

1. trunk -> branch (merge)

   - cd my_project_branch
   - svn merge https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/my_project/trunk/my_project ~/workspaceAssembla/my_project_branch
   - svn commit -m "1. trunk -> branch" *
2. made changes on branch

   - cd my_project_branch
   - svn commit -m "2. made changes on branch" *
3. branch -> trunk (merge)

   - cd my_project_trunk
   - svn merge --reintegrate https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/my_project/branches/my_project ~/workspaceAssembla/my_project_trunk
   - svn commit -m "3. branch -> trunk (merge)" *
4. made changes on trunk

   - cd my_project_trunk
   - svn commit -m "4. made changes on trunk" *
5. trunk -> branch (merge but forgot one change!) [i.e. merged change was NOT committed to branch]

   - cd my_project_branch
   - svn merge https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/my_project/trunk/my_project ~/workspaceAssembla/my_project_branch
   - svn commit -m "5. trunk -> branch (merge but forgot one change!)" * (**not all files were committed!!!**)
6. look at branch
7. figure out something is missed
8. try to merge trunk -> branch again to resolve the missed things

   - cd my_project_branch
   - svn merge https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/my_project/trunk/my_project ~/workspaceAssembla/my_project_branch
9. bump! No changes to merge!

In other words I can see that I have a change at trunk that should be at branch but I can't merge it for this moment (because it was partially merged). Is there some remedy for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exact set of commands that duplicates this scenario I'd be interested in seeing it (start with a new repo and go from there).  If so with what version of Subversion did you duplicate it.

That said, if you want to merge something that Subversion is ignoring it's probably due to mergeinfo.  In this case you probably can just do a cherry-pick merge with `--ignore-ancestry` i.e. `svn merge -c 1234 --ignore-ancestry ^/trunk` where revision r1234 is the one that has the change you want to merge.

Comment: I think SVN version is not a problem here I think it's common SVN problem(?). I used 1.7.8. I reproduced the scenario from scratch on  clear repository. The list of commands is standard (I used Subclipse plugin for this): co,up,commit,merge - nothing sophisticated. Unfortunately your solution didn't work for me - after your command I can't see lost change in my file.

Comment: Can you please include the exact commands that were used to reproduce the issue in your question.  A lot has changed since 1.7.8, especially related to merging, your assertion that it's a common issue with Subversion doesn't mean much.

Comment: Please see my update. I've added commands for provided steps.

Comment: It is very hard to help with merge issues in the abstract.  History plays a very important role in merging.  Without seeing the history of the repo I can't tell what's going on with the merge.  That's why I asked for you to come up with a reproduction recipe that started with a new repository (that allows me to see every bit of history since you're providing every command run against the repository).  I know that's inconvenient.  The only other alternative is giving access to the repository.